# Custom pagebreak in align equation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, page-breaking, align

I got the following problem: Right now I am checking my equations, which are usually written in `align`. This looks great in most of the cases, but sometimes the pagebreaks are weird, ie there is a lot of vertical whitespace left (like 2.5cm) at the end of a page. I made the following MWE to illustrate this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
% \usepackage{lipsum} %\lipsum
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[1][3]%1 paragraph, 3 pangrams
\begin{align}
X_{t+1} &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \label{eq:1} 
\intertext{Solving...:} \notag 
X_{t}  &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_{t+1}} \notag \\
\intertext{Solving further...:} \notag 
% ===PAGEBREAK HERE: 2nd page begins===
&= \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t} + 
\frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \notag \\
&= \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}...  \notag \\
\intertext{Solving further...:} & = \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \notag
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

In the MWE, the first 'Solving further' should be on the first page instead (to save space and it would also look better I guess?). The position where I would like the pagebreak to be is also marked as a comment in the MWE.

My question is first on a general basis: Which is the best environment to achieve multiple line equations, which can be aligned as in `align`, and to save space at the same time? Or to be more precise: If possible, I'd like to stick with `align` and adapt the pagebreaks only if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: but, from p.189 of the texbook: "Plain TeX sets `\predisplaypenalty=100000`, because fine printers traditionally shun displayed formulas at the very top of a page."  you might consider using `\shortintertext` (defined in `mathtools`) to save space when the text really doesn't overlap the displayed material.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ok so you recommend not to follow the below solution, but instead to use `shortintertext` cmds?

Comment: it's your paper, so it's really your choice.  but you might try `\shortintertext` to see if it's an improvement.  it *might* set the lines closer together than you want, because you're using `onehalfspacing`, but math displays always get extra space anyhow.  the only way to find out is to try it in your particular context.

Comment: @barbarabeeton alright thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want automatic page breaks you have to use the command `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble.

If you want manual page breaks, you have to use the command `\displaybreak` followed by `\\`, as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
% \usepackage{lipsum} %\lipsum
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[1][3]%5 paragraphs, each 3 pangrams
\begin{align}
X_{t+1} &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \label{eq:1}
\intertext{Solving...:} \notag
X_{t}  &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_{t+1}} \notag \\
\intertext{Solving further...:} \notag \displaybreak\\
% ===PAGEBREAK HERE: 2nd page begins===
&= \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t} +
\frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \notag \\
&= \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}...  \notag \\
\intertext{Solving further...:} & = \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use

```
[...]
\allowdisplaybreaks%%%%%
\begin{document}
\Blindtext[1][3]%5 paragraphs, each 3 pangrams
\begin{align}
X_{t+1} &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \label{eq:1} 
\intertext{Solving...:} \notag 
X_{t}  &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_{t+1}} \notag \\
\intertext{Solving further...:}
&= \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t} + \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \notag \\
&= \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}...  \notag \\
\intertext{Solving further...:} & = \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  \notag
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'd accepted both if possible because both are correct. To be fair I accepted the faster entry.