# Correct typesetting of aligned (or multiline etc) equations after a pagebreak

Tags: amsmath, align, typography

I was writing a block of mathematical formulas using the `align` environment. While I was writing these aligned equations I reached a pagebreak and the whole block moved to the next page so it made me wonder what is the right way to typeset my aligned equations in that case so to have the best output.

That environment doesn't allow pagebreaks as it is mentioned in the Amsmath's user manual so in such a case the author to be responsible for the breaking of the equations.

So in such a case should I leave most of the equations in the `align` environment till the pagebreak and the rest of them in a new `align`? If there is only one equation left that doesn't fit in the page should I use again `align` or a simple `equation` environment in order to have the same alignment with the previous block of equations? Does the `equation` environment aligns the one leftover equation the same as the block of equations in the previous page?

Also what should I do in the case that I had used the `multiline` or one of the other environments?

Comment: Put `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

Comment: `amsmath` doesn't do automatic breaking of alignment environments exactly because doing so requires judgment. Break after the line where this does the least damage by putting `\displaybreak` before the terminating ``\\``. Avoid using `\allowdisplaybreaks` except when just typing the document, because this will break displays without a real criterion. Remove it when the document is ready and you want to fix the page break, looking at every display that doesn't fit.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Custom pagebreak in align equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151129/579)